# I need to change a required field to not required

Tags: page-layout

I want to change one of my field from required field to not required field (for specific Page Layout) and I tried the next process (Go to Your Name | Setup | App Setup | Select the object you need to change the field on | Page Layouts | Click edit next to the specific page layout | go to the field on the page layout editor and select the wrench icon )  but I can not uncheck the checkbox for required field, the field is grayed out.

Any idea how to do that in other way (without changing anything on field in Object but only on Page layout)?
[image]

Comment: If the field is required at object level, it's required.  No getting around it.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

Comment: I've added it as an answer so this question doesn't float around as an unaswered question.  i.e. please accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is required at object level, it's required. No getting around it.